# Is it correct to use Kafka consumer pool?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, pool

Time to time, I need to read records from specific partition with specific offset of same topic.

I can create new kafka consumer for each time. However, I can create pool of consumers and use it in this way:

```
List<KafkaConsumer> consumers = new ArrayList<>();

// acquire consumer
KafkaConsumer consumer = consumers.get(0);
TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition("my-topic", 42);
consumer.assign(List.of(topicPartition));
consumer.seek(topicPartition, 13);

ConsumerRecords records = consumer.poll(0);
// process records
// .....

// release consumer
consumer.unsubscribe();
```

Should I make consumer pool? Or it is not effective, and I should create new consumer for each using.

Answer (score 2):

You need just one consumer. Just unsubscribe and reassign it to another `TopicPartition`.

```
String topic = "my-topic";
int partition = 42;
int offset = 13;
boolean running = true;

while(running) {
    TopicPartition topicPartition = new TopicPartition(topic, partition);
    consumer.assign(List.of(topicPartition));
    consumer.seek(topicPartition, offset);

    ConsumerRecords records = consumer.poll(0);
    // process records
    // .....

    // release consumer
    consumer.unsubscribe();
    // Change topic, partition, offset as needed
}
```

Comment: You didn't mention about threads. now you can read a message and pass it to thread worker. while the thread is doing its job you can read another message.

Comment: so, let's consider 300 threads, which want to read smt from topic. They will be blocked, while waiting for consumer read `record` for them. So, in this place we want to create more consumers, than 1. And it is my question about consumer pool.